# Find $\sigma$-field $\sigma(\mathscr A)$ generated by $\mathscr A$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega =\{1,2,3,4\}$, and let $\mathscr A = \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.
Find $\sigma$-field $\sigma(\mathscr A)$ generated by $\mathscr A$.

My answer is $\sigma(\mathscr A) = \mathscr A \cup \mathscr A^c = \{\{1\},\{2\}\} \cup \{\{3\},\{4\}\} = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$. Because 1. $\Omega \subset \sigma(\mathscr A)$, 2. $A \in \sigma(\mathscr A)$ and $A^c \in \sigma(\mathscr A)$ 3. $\cup^\infty_{n=1}A_n \in \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\} \in \sigma(\mathscr A)$.

Can anyone help me to check if it is right? And will there be many other solution?

Comment: What about the set $\{1,2\}$? Even that should belong to $\sigma(\mathscr A)$.

Comment: yep, you are right. I think what I need to add is the power set for the complement.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, $\mathscr A$ does not differentiate between $3$ and $4$, and so you should not expect that the *smallest sigma algebra* $\sigma(\mathscr A)$ containing $\mathscr A$ to contain either $\{ 3\}$ or $\{ 4\}$. Moreover, you need complements of $\{ 1\}, \{ 2 \}$, so e.g. $\{ 1,3,4\}$ should also be included.

Formally, I find it useful to work with *partitions*. The partition of $\Omega$ corresponding to $\mathscr A$ is $\mathcal P = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 3,4\}\}$; precisely, we have $\sigma(\mathscr A) = \sigma(\mathcal P)$. All we have done here is filled out our partition with the complement of $\{ 1 \} \cup \{ 2 \}$ in $\Omega$.

Now, since $\mathcal P$ is a partition, $\sigma(\mathcal P)$ consists of all possible combinations of unions of atoms in $\mathcal P$, including $\emptyset$. I'll leave it to you to write out the full list, although I will mention that neither $\{ 3\}$ nor $\{ 4 \}$ will make it into $\sigma(\mathcal P) = \sigma(\mathscr A)$.